# Connecting Java with Google Calendar

Tags: java, scheduling, google-calendar-api

I'm relatively new to Java, so I have little to no idea where to even start with this one.  I'm writing a scheduling application using Java and google calendars.  On my google account I have a bunch of calendars with people's schedules on them. I need to access these calendars through java and insert the person's free / busy information into arrays like so:

```
    //User 1
    int[][] swift_schedule = new int[5][6];
    //1 = busy, 0 = free

    //Monday
    swift_schedule[0][0] = 0;  //9-11
    swift_schedule[0][1] = 1;  //11-1
    swift_schedule[0][2] = 1;  //1-3
    swift_schedule[0][3] = 1;  //3-5
    swift_schedule[0][4] = 1;  //5-7
    swift_schedule[0][5] = 1;  //7-9
    //Tuesday
    swift_schedule[1][0] = 0; //9-11
    swift_schedule[1][1] = 0; //11-1
    swift_schedule[1][2] = 0; //1-3

    etc....
```

If I were using PHP, I would get a url for the XML feed and just parse the data out of it, but with JAVA I don't even know where to start. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Tutorials, code snippets, and other hints would be greatly appreciated!

cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do the parsing when there is a Java API for it, simply use it and query for the calendar events you want.

With [DateTime](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/DateTime.html) and [CalendarQuery](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/calendar/CalendarQuery.html) you can query for events in a specific time interval (your use case: to get events in a give day).

```
CalendarQuery myQuery = new CalendarQuery(feedUrl);
myQuery.setMinimumStartTime(DateTime.parseDateTime("2006-03-16T00:00:00"));
myQuery.setMaximumStartTime(DateTime.parseDateTime("2006-03-24T23:59:59"));
```

> Google Calendar allows client
>   applications to view and update
>   calendar events in the form of Google
>   Data API feeds. Your client
>   application can use the [Google
>   Calendar Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html) to create new
>   events, edit or delete existing
>   events, and query for events that
>   match particular criteria.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes life a lot easier. Any idea where I can find some up to date instructions on getting it to work with eclipse on Windows? Everything I've found is either written for linux or is out dated.